# IE8, transparent PNG and filter:alpha

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, opacity, alpha

I'll cut right to the point. Here's the output:

[image]

(now some optional code - read only if you really want to ;))

Here's the markup:

```
<a href="/" id="logo_wrapper">
    <span class="logo logo_normal"></span>
    <span class="logo logo_hover"></span>
</a>
```

Here's the CSS (shortened only to the relevant stuff, for your reading pleasure):

```
#logo_wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#logo_wrapper .logo {
  display:block;
  width:260px;
  height:80px;
  background-image:url(logo.png);
  position:absolute;
}
#logo_wrapper .logo_normal {
  background-position:0 0;
}
#logo_wrapper .logo_normal:hover {
  opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
#logo_wrapper .logo_hover {
  background-position:0 -80px;
  opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
#logo_wrapper .logo_hover:hover {
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* THIS IS THE OFFENDER! */
}
```

Just to clarify: I'm aware I can get away with a single `span` and just switching the logo's `background-position` on hover, but the full CSS features cute CSS3 transitions for real browsers that aren't supposed to scroll the logo up and down.

OK, so, it's a PNG with 32 bit colour depth and, of course, transparency. All is fine in IE8 when I use no alpha filter at all or `filter:alpha(opacity=0)`. But with the opacity set to 100, the mere use of the filter causes IE8 to go crazy and make all not entirely transparent pixels 100% opaque. Not that this particular image looks all that bad with this effect, but it's still annoying :D.

Now, I'm well aware IE8 is notorious for transparent PNG problems, with the troubles dating back to IE6 and its hideous solid cyan fill of the transparent areas. That one could be fixed with some IE behaviour black magic.

**What can be done about IE8?**

Comment: IE8 can be destroyed and buried alive and never looked at again. I am sorry that's probably not the answer you were looking for. :)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree :D. I hate it as much as you do, trust me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `AlphaImageLoader` filter, just like for IE6.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, but it appears that IE is completely ignoring this. This is my declaration: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='logo.png', sizingMethod='scale')alpha(opacity=100);` - the result is exactly the same as before x_x... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hm, in fact, it's even worse: using it doesn't display any image at all. I'm a bit puzzled here...

Comment: @mingos: Yes; you need to separate the filters with a `,`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm too sleepy to try it now, but I'll get back to this tomorrow evening :).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work at all. The image does not appear at all :(.

Comment: Nope, the image doesn't appear at all with AlphaImageLoader. I decided to just leave it be and let IE users worry. I accepted your answer because I have no alternative that would work for me :(.

Comment: @mingos: Try using IE's Javascript filter API; it might help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll investigate it, but perhaps for a project I'm getting paid for :D.

Comment: so you never fix it. you drop it :(

Answer (score 9):

A simple fix: just **add a background color to .logo_hover:hover** and alpha filter works fine again.

Obviously this fix is not always useful (that is, if you can't use a background color below your png that mimics the real background).

Comment: the background color fixes it for me and I've never thought of that :) Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='logo.png', sizingMethod='scale', alpha(opacity=100));
```

Thanks SLaks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter:none` in your `:hover` class.